# React.js / Webpack inject new main.js file after every build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I am working on a React project which has a production version as well.
For some reason in the past developments now **only for some users** react project is cached on their browser. Not all parts, but **some parts are cached**.

In the index.html file after every build, these two import names are the same as this.

[image]

So I guess these two files are cached in some browsers.

Is there a way to generate a new file name for these two files for each build. So that we can ensure this won't be cache anymore.

My react version is `"16.8.6"`
and for the moment I don't have a `webpack.config.js` file.

How do I achieve this with React / Webpack?

Comment: Normally the hashes before `.chunk` get changed by webpack during a new deploy to prevent the caching problem. Maybe someone changed webpacks behavior?

Comment: Files should be cached. Different files must NOT have same names (things like 0e5dfc58 is file hash sum and should be unique). You need first to check if "chunk has changed and its name not" is your actual problem.